# How to strip leading "http://" from char array in C?

Tags: c, string

I have a function (in C) that is passed a URL. This function only works if the URL parameter is in the form of `www.example.com`, not when it is `http://www.example.com`.

I would like to modify this function so that, when passed a URL in the form of `http://www.example.com`, it strips the leading `http://` (if present), so that it will operate correctly.

How would I do this in C?

Here's the function in question (let me know if there is a better way to do this):

```
char* get_ip (char* url)
{
    struct hostent* h;
    if ((h = gethostbyname(url)) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*)h->h_addr));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's always the simple approach:

```
char *url;
// ...
const char *http = "http://";
if (!strncmp(url, http, strlen(http)))
    url += strlen(http);
```

Or, if you want to get rid of protocol specifiers of that form in general (e.g., https):

```
char *url;
char *p = strstr(url, "://");
if (p)
    url = p + 3; // skip past :// part of URL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char* get_ip (char* url)
{
    struct hostent* h;

    if (strncasecmp(url, "http://", 7) == 0)
        url += 7;
    else if (strncasecmp(url, "https://", 8) == 0)
        url += 8;

    if ((h = gethostbyname(url)) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*)h->h_addr));
}
```

Comment: To get it working for other schemes like ftp too, you could simply extract the part between `://` and the next `/` (if it exists). If the host-part contains a `@`, the hostname starts right of that character. A special case is file:///xyz, which would result in a null string and should return `localhost`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply compare the first seven characters of the array to see if it matches "http://", and if that's the case, then split the string right after that point.  So you could do the following:

```
char* full_url = "http://www.example.com";
char* final_url = NULL;

//copy the header into a temporary buffer
char[8] http_header;
strncpy(http_header, full_url, sizeof(http_header));
http_header[7] = '\0'; //NULL-terminate the string

if (strcmp(http_header, "http://") == 0)
    final_url = &full_url[7];
else
    final_url = full_url;
```

The only thing to be careful about with this code is that whatever `final_url` is pointing to has a lifespan that extends past the lifespan of `final_url` ... otherwise `final_url` will not be pointing to valid memory anymore.  This shouldn't be an issue though inside of a function that is passed a pointer to a string, where `final_url` is only used inside the function itself.